# What was the matter with the woman in the bathroom?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-defector

During the beginning of [*The Defector* (orig.: *L'espion*)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060295/) *Prof. Bower* enters his hotel room and surprises a naked woman that is taking a bath in his bathroom. She excuses herself and says that she's living one floor up, her bathroom is not working and she thought this room to be empty. She then leaves the sightly perplexed *Bower* in a towel and seems to head to her room. Yet on the floor in front of *Bower*'s room she is called into another room by a man standing in an open door.

**I wonder what this scene was all about**, since it isn't picked up at any later point in the story and I'm not sure what to make of all this. Was this really just a distraction without any relevance to the rest of the plot or was there more to it that I just didn't get? Was this already part of the Stasi's attempt to turn *Bower* crazy? Or maybe it was a dropped story arc and the source novel might give some explanation.

Comment: I'm struggling to remember or locate that scene. Can you provide a timestamp?

Comment: @Richard Oh, that's hard to do, I watched that ages (or 1.5 years) ago on TV. It was rather at the beginning I think, when he just arrived in Germany, I think.

Comment: Helpfully, someone has posted the full movie online here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q4Rk-JV_CHA.

Comment: @Richard Thanks, I might try to look into that again.

Comment: I'm still at a loss to find that scene. He only goes to into his hotel room at about halfway through the film.

Comment: @Richard Strange, it's supposed to be right before the weird night in the hotel room near the beginning (at ~0:25 maybe). Unfortunatey I've finally deleted it from my DVR just a few weeks ago. But that scene was definitely there.

Comment: I've watched the version online and a DVD version I (ahem) acquired on the interwebs. I'm still not seeing it. Did you perhaps dream it?

Comment: @Richard Seriously, I'm still 99% sure the scene was definitely in that movie. I asked that question right after I'd seen the film. I don't think I slept away either. This is really odd.

Comment: Have you come off your meds recently?

Comment: @Richard No. Maybe it was just the Russians who tried to drive me crazy.

Comment: Being slipped LSD by the KGB while working for the CIA would certainly explain your FMS

Comment: I've voted to close this one. I can't find the scene in question and OP can't either :-)

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I'm at a loss why you've voted to keep this open. The scene (as far as I can tell) doesn't occur in the film and Napoleon has been unable to offer a timestamp for precisely that reason.

Comment: @Valorum Now wait a second. You're in your good right to close-vote this. However, the statement that *"Napoleon has been unable to offer a timestamp for precisely that reason"* is plain wrong. The reason I haven't been able to provide a timestamp is *not* because the scene doesn't occur in the film, but because I saw the damned thing 10 years ago on TV and never again (and well, didn't keep track of timestamps for possible future questions). The scene might not exist (I'm sure it does, though). But saying I can't find it, is simply not true. What about *you* try harder to track it down? ;-)

Comment: It might possibly not be in the official novelization. ;-)

Comment: The film is available online here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JaJswsRUufQ amongst other sources. Please feel free to locate the scene in question.

Comment: Well, we already know the version on YouTube apparently doesn't contain it.

Comment: I've also checked the version on Turner Classic Movies. Both versions on Youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zk7Tw8lyZ1Y) seem pretty much complete, minus a few seconds of the end credits

Comment: IMDb claims there's also one which is 6 minutes longer (which is also the length Wikipedia gives). Although it's apparently the US version, which I would be less likely to have seen.